# Get country code using pycountry from a user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, country-codes

I am trying to convert a country name to the desired country code.

For example:

```
United Kingdom : UK
```

I have attempted the following:

```
import pycountry
user_input = raw_input(': ')
mapping = {country.name: country.alpha2 for country in pycountry.countries}
print mapping.get(user_input)
```

I believe I may have misunderstood the documentation, since I receive the following error:

```
    mapping = {country.name: country.alpha2 for country in pycountry.countries}
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycountry/db.py", line 22, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

Comment: Should be `country.alpha_2` not `country.alpha2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import pycountry
user_input = raw_input(': ')
mapping = {country.name: country.alpha_2 for country in pycountry.countries}
print mapping.get(user_input)
```

is the correct way you are using 'alpha2' instead of alpha_2

Comment: please always use dir() while dealing with a new module

Answer (score 2):

For **Python3**, I believe that using the Pytz built-in module will be easier

```
>> import pytz
>> print(pytz.country_names['tn'])
Tunisia
```